# Recursive method to build a tree with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to translate the next example of a Bernoulli tree built with  pst-tree with tikz but I don't know if it's possible :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-tree}

\makeatletter

\newcount\@Bernoudepth
\newcount\@Bernoumaxdepth

\newcommand\Bernoutree[8][treemode=R,nodesep=1ex,levelsep=12ex]{%
  % #2 = depth of tree
  % #3 = name for success
  % #4 = name for miss
  % #5 = probability of a success
  % #6 = position of  #5
  % #7 = probability of a miss 
  % #8 = position of #7
  \begingroup
  % initialize  parameters
  \psset{treemode=R,nodesep=1ex,levelsep=12ex}%
  \psset{#1}%
  \@Bernoumaxdepth #2\relax
  \def\@Reussite{#3}%
  \def\@Echec{#4}%
  \def\@probareussite{#5}%
  \def\@Argreussite{#6}%
  % if no parameter of position
  % center position 
  \ifx\empty\@Argreussite
    \def\@Argreussite{0.5}%
  \fi
  \def\@probaechec{#7}%
  \def\@Argechec{#8}
  \ifx\empty\@Argechec
    \def\@Argechec{0.5}%
  \fi
  % First call  (empty root, level 1)
  \pstree{\TR{}}{\@Bernoutree{1}}
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand\@Bernoutree[1]{%
  % #1 = recursive depth 
  % initialize the depth
  \@Bernoudepth #1\relax
  \ifnum\@Bernoudepth=\@Bernoumaxdepth
    % if depth  max is reached
    % we place the two final nodes
    \TR{\@Reussite}\taput[tpos=\@Argreussite]{\@probareussite}
    \TR{\@Echec}\tbput[tpos=\@Argechec]{\@probaechec}
    % it's finished
  \else
    % else we build with a recursive method
    % the two branches of higher level
    \advance\@Bernoudepth \@ne
    \pstree{\TR{\@Reussite}\taput[tpos=\@Argreussite]
           {\@probareussite}}{\@Bernoutree{\the\@Bernoudepth}}
    \pstree{\TR{\@Echec}\tbput[tpos=\@Argechec]
           {\@probaechec}}{\@Bernoutree{\the\@Bernoudepth}}
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\Bernoutree[levelsep=18ex,treenodesize=0pt]{4}{$R$}{$E$}{$p$}{}{$q$}{}

\end{document}
```

Actually I get the tree with the next method but it's not a recursive method.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{trees,arrows} 

\makeatletter
\newcount\tkz@Berndepth
\newdimen\tkz@BernLEN
\tkz@BernLEN=24em 
\def\tkzBernTreeSet#{\pgfqkeys{/berntree}} 

\pgfqkeys{/berntree}{%
  success/.code      = \def\tkz@bern@success{#1},
  miss/.code         = \def\tkz@bern@miss{#1},
  p/.code            = \def\tkz@bern@pbsuccess{#1},
  q/.code            = \def\tkz@bern@pbmiss{#1},
  node success style/.style  = {inner sep=2pt,outer sep=3pt},
  node miss style/.style     = {inner sep=2pt,outer sep=3pt},
  edge style/.style  = {->,>=latex',shorten <= 6pt},
  root style/.style  = {draw,circle},
  success/.initial   = S,
  miss/.initial      = E, 
  p/.initial         = $p$,
  q/.initial         = $1-p$,
  gap/.code          = \def\tkz@bern@gap{#1},
  length/.code       = \def\tkz@bern@length{#1} 
} 

\def\tkz@brntree#1#2{%
  \node[/berntree/root style] {};
\global\advance\tkz@Berndepth 1\relax
\begin{scope}[level distance=\tkz@bern@length,
              level 1/.style={sibling distance=#2}]   
  \node[] (root) at (#1) {}     
  [grow=right]
  child[/berntree/edge style] {%
    node[/berntree/node miss style](tkz@E\the\tkz@Berndepth) {\tkz@bern@miss} 
            edge from parent node[fill=white] {\tkz@bern@pbmiss}}
  child [/berntree/edge style] {%
    node[/berntree/node success style] (tkz@S\the\tkz@Berndepth) {\tkz@bern@success} 
            edge from parent node[fill=white] {\tkz@bern@pbsuccess}
             };
\end{scope}}% 

\def\tkzBernTree{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tkz@BernTree}{\tkz@BernTree[]}}
\def\tkz@BernTree[#1]#2{%
\begingroup  
\pgfqkeys{/berntree}{%
success = S,
miss= E,
node success style/.style  = {inner sep=2pt,outer sep=3pt,draw,minimum width=1.5em,minimum height=1.5em},
node miss style/.style  = {inner sep=2pt,outer sep=3pt,circle,draw,minimum width=1.5em},
p=$p$,
q=$q$,
gap=8cm,
length=3cm} 
\pgfqkeys{/berntree}{#1}
  \tkz@BernLEN=\tkz@bern@gap\relax    
  \tkz@Berndepth 0\relax 
  \node (tkz@S0) at (0,0){}; 
\def\tkz@bn@level{#2} 
 \ifcase\tkz@bn@level%
 \or% 
  \tkz@brntree{tkz@S0}{\tkz@BernLEN} 
 \or% 
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S0}{\tkz@BernLEN} 
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {1}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}
 \or%
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S0}{\tkz@BernLEN}  
   \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {1}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}   
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {2,3}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}} 
 \or% 
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S0}{\tkz@BernLEN}  
   \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {1}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}   
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {2,3}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}} 
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {4,5,6,7}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}    
  \or% 
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S0}{\tkz@BernLEN}  
   \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {1}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}   
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {2,3}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}} 
  \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {4,...,7}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}} 
   \divide \tkz@BernLEN by 2 %
 \foreach \nd in {8,...,15}{   
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@S\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}
   \tkz@brntree{tkz@E\nd}{\tkz@BernLEN}}   
 \fi   
 \endgroup
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[yscale=1.2]
 \tkzBernTree[root style/.style  = {fill,circle,outer sep =1pt,inner sep=2pt}]{4}

 \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the code from [`tikz-qtree`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree) might be useful to look at.

Comment: Yes good idea...

Comment: Forest would be the obvious choice these days ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a possible solution. I had to separate the node creation and the labelling of the edges. I've also been thinking of doing this with a lindenmayer system but that failed. Enjoy. (I minimised on style settings and focussed on the nub of the matter.)

The tree creation wasn't so straightforward and I had to fight hard to increment and decrement the TeX counter \depth. In the end I ended up doing this as part of a node style. It also required the placement of a dummy coordinate that incremented the level upon returning from the recursion.

The labelling exploits the fact that tikz labels the children of a parent with the labels (parent-1), (parent-2), ..., where (parent) is the label of the parent.

The rest is pretty much straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}      
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  

\newcount\depth

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bernoulliTree[1]{%
    \depth=#1\relax            
    \draw node(root)[bernoulli/root] {}[grow=right] \draw@bernoulli@tree;
    \draw \label@bernoulli@tree{root};                                   
}                                                                        

\def\draw@bernoulli@tree{%
    \ifnum\depth>0        
      child foreach \type/\label in {left child/$S$,right child/$F$} {%
          node[bernoulli/\type]{\label} \draw@bernoulli@tree
      }
      coordinate[bernoulli/increment] (dummy)
   \fi%
}

\def\label@bernoulli@tree#1{%
    \ifnum\depth>0
      ($(#1)!0.5!(#1-1)$) node[fill=white,bernoulli/decrement] {$p$}
      \label@bernoulli@tree{#1-1}
      ($(#1)!0.5!(#1-2)$) node[fill=white] {$1-p$}
      \label@bernoulli@tree{#1-2}
      coordinate[bernoulli/increment] (dummy)
   \fi%
}

\makeatother

\tikzset{bernoulli/.cd,
         root/.style={circle,fill,black},
         decrement/.code=\global\advance\depth by-1\relax,
         increment/.code=\global\advance\depth by 1\relax,
         left child/.style={draw,bernoulli/decrement},
         right child/.style={draw,circle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2cm,
                    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
                    level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
\bernoulliTree{3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

Comment: This looks very promising. I need to study attentively your code. At the first approach, perhaps it's possible to integrate the `sibling distance` automatically.

Comment: Thanks. As I said, the most difficult was to adjust the counter. The tikz/pgf parser won't allow much when it's parsing a tree. It is possible to include the sibling distance automatically, but I wanted to keep the example simple. (It is also possible to do without the ``child foreach'' but I thought the current version is neater.)

Comment: Neat code; very elegant !

Answer (score 3):

Forest lends itself easily to think kind of automation. The following provides a Forest style, `Bernoulli`, together with a wrapper macro, `\bernoullitree[<options>]`, which takes one optional argument. As is more common now, and ubiquitous in the Ti*k*Z world, configuration uses a key-value interface. If using the macro form, `<options>` may contain `Bernoulli`-style-specific keys and/or Forest keys and/or Ti*k*Z keys.

One example of the style used directly in a tree and three examples using the macro wrapper are given.

```
\begin{forest}
  Bernoulli,
  tree depth'=3,
  success name=R,
  miss name=E,
  miss probability=q
  []
\end{forest}
```

This shows the effect of mixing default settings (not specified) with custom values for some keys.

```
\bernoullitree
```

produces a tree with the default settings (which could be changed globally, if required, of course, either by editing my defaults or later changing them with `\forestset`).

The third tree shows the effect of passing a range of custom values to the macro `\bernoullitree`.

```
\bernoullitree[tree depth'=3,success name=R, miss name=E, miss probability=q, root style'=draw, miss style=red, success style=blue, miss edge style={red, densely dashed}, success edge style=blue]
```

Finally, the last example shows that the direction of growth may be easily modified, should you require a south-growing tree, say, rather than one headed in a westwards direction.

```
\bernoullitree[before typesetting nodes={for tree={grow'=-90, tier/.option=level}},miss label=above]
```

[image: sample selection of Bernoulli trees]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  declare toks register={success name},
  declare toks register={miss name},
  declare toks register={success probability},
  declare toks register={miss probability},
  declare count register={tree depth},
  declare keylist register={success style},
  declare keylist register={miss style},
  declare keylist register={root style},
  declare keylist register={miss edge style},
  declare keylist register={success edge style},
  declare toks register={success label},
  declare toks register={miss label},
  tree depth'=4,
  success name=S,
  miss name=M,
  success probability=p,
  miss probability=1-p,
  success style={circle, draw},
  miss style={circle, draw},
  success edge style={},
  miss edge style={},
  root style={circle, fill, draw},
  success label=above,
  miss label=below,
  bernoulli label/.style={
    edge label/.process={RRw2{#1 probability}{#1 label}{node [midway, sloped, ##2] {$##1$}}},
  },
  Bernoulli/.style={
    delay={
      \forestregister{root style},
      tempcounta'=0,
      do while={
        >RR<{tempcounta}{tree depth}
      }{
        where n children=0{append={[,content/.register=miss name,\forestregister{miss style},edge+/.register=miss edge style,bernoulli label=miss,]},prepend={[,content/.register=success name,\forestregister{success style},edge+/.register=success edge style,bernoulli label=success,]}}{},
        do dynamics,
        tempcounta/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
      }
    },
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        grow'=0,
        math content,
        l sep'+=15pt,
        s sep'+=5pt,
      },
    },
  },
}
\newcommand\bernoullitree[1][]{\begin{forest}Bernoulli,#1[]\end{forest}}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  Bernoulli,
  tree depth'=3,
  success name=R,
  miss name=E,
  miss probability=q
  []
\end{forest}
\bernoullitree
\bernoullitree[tree depth'=3,success name=R, miss name=E, miss probability=q, root style'=draw, miss style=red, success style=blue, miss edge style={red, densely dashed}, success edge style=blue]
\bernoullitree[before typesetting nodes={for tree={grow'=-90, tier/.option=level}},miss label=above]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also improve what was nicely done by user10274 by modifying it a little, such that it gives also the probabilities you want on the branches : I had to do it in order to use it in a same document but with different configurations. This gives the same output as the one obtained by user10274 :

```
%command :          \bernoulliTree{#attempts}{p}{1-p} 

%  Bernoulli tree - Schéma de Bernoulli - arbre pondéré

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}      
\usetikzlibrary{calc}  

\newcount\depth

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\bernoulliTree[3]{%
\depth=#1\relax            
\draw node(root)[bernoulli/root] {}[grow=right] \draw@bernoulli@tree;
\draw \label@bernoulli@tree{root}{#2}{#3};                           
}                                                                        

\def\draw@bernoulli@tree{%
\ifnum\depth>0        
  child foreach \type/\label in {left child/$S$,right child/$F$} {%
      node[bernoulli/\type]{\label} \draw@bernoulli@tree
  }
  coordinate[bernoulli/increment] (dummy)
   \fi%
}

\def\label@bernoulli@tree#1#2#3{%
\ifnum\depth>0
  ($(#1)!0.5!(#1-1)$) node[fill=white,bernoulli/decrement] {{\small $#2$}}
  \label@bernoulli@tree{#1-1}{#2}{#3}
  ($(#1)!0.5!(#1-2)$) node[fill=white] {{\small $#3$}}
  \label@bernoulli@tree{#1-2}{#2}{#3}
  coordinate[bernoulli/increment] (dummy)
   \fi%
}

\makeatother

\tikzset{bernoulli/.cd,
     root/.style={circle,fill,black},
     decrement/.code=\global\advance\depth by-1\relax,
     increment/.code=\global\advance\depth by 1\relax,
     left child/.style={draw,bernoulli/decrement},
     right child/.style={draw,circle}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=2cm,
                level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
                level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm}]
\bernoulliTree{3}{p}{1-p}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Could you explain your modifications and improvements a little bit more? Where are the differences to the other answer?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Isn't `\label@bernoulli@tree` differently defined?

Comment: @Bobyandbob However, the output looks identical when I compile it, so I'm not sure what it is meant to do exactly.

Comment: Sorry to answer this day. What does the modification \bernoulliTree{3}{p}{1-p} compared to \bernoulliTree{3} of user 10274 is that you can create a tree and change the probabilities between two trees, what the one of user 10274 does not (I guess).
I am using his code and just use \bernoulliTree{3}{0.2}{0.8}, ....
Your code @cfr seems however better.